# jquery uncaught error typehead is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

i knew there are several threads like this.
i already tried the solutions that told in those kind of threads.
but none of them work in my case.

so here my codes :

```
var mv = ['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona', 'Arkansas', 'California',
              'Colorado', 'Connecticut', 'Delaware', 'Florida', 'Georgia', 'Hawaii',
              'Idaho', 'Illinois', 'Indiana', 'Iowa', 'Kansas', 'Kentucky', 'Louisiana',
              'Maine', 'Maryland', 'Massachusetts', 'Michigan', 'Minnesota',
              'Mississippi', 'Missouri', 'Montana', 'Nebraska', 'Nevada', 'New Hampshire',
              'New Jersey', 'New Mexico', 'New York', 'North Carolina', 'North Dakota',
              'Ohio', 'Oklahoma', 'Oregon', 'Pennsylvania', 'Rhode Island',
              'South Carolina', 'South Dakota', 'Tennessee', 'Texas', 'Utah', 'Vermont',
              'Virginia', 'Washington', 'West Virginia', 'Wisconsin', 'Wyoming' ,'this is for test purposes only okay this sentence is verrrryyy loooooong '
             ];

$('.mv-type').typeahead(null, {
    name: 'mv-type',
    limit: 10,
    source: substringMatcher(mv) ,
    hint: true,
    highlight: true,
    minLength: 1
});
```

the funny things is, its work on my online project.
but when i goes in localhost, i got error typehead is not a function.

please help me.
thanks.

Comment: What is  typeahead?

Comment: I assume `.typeahead()` is a jQuery plugin - have you included it via a `<script>` element?

Comment: did you cross reference your script references from your online project with your local project ,if typeahead() is a library ,did u include a reference  to it

Comment: Check if your jquery is loaded properly